# Ignite Backup of Directory from 2.7.6 to 2.14

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I have a copy of a ignite cache directory copied from old installation

cache-SQL_PUBLIC_TEST003

I have copied it to new installation db/node-xxxx/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_TEST003
After activating and restarting the cluster I am runing the query, but its giving error for node id issue, how to get backed up data with new node id?

```
Error: Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=38401b6d-3f24-4ae1-a7b8-9893e27f882c, errMsg=General error: "class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Cannot find metadata for object with compact footer (Ignite work directory might have been cleared after restart. Make sure that IGNITE_HOME does not point to a temp folder or any other folder that is destroyed/cleared on restarts) [typeId=-60479141, IGNITE_HOME='/opt/ignite/apache-ignite']"; SQL statement:
SELECT
__Z0.NAME __C0_0,
__Z0.ID __C0_1
FROM PUBLIC.TEST001 __Z0 [50000-197]] (state=50000,code=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the *whole* persistence directory of your old cluster, you can *probably* start a cluster with the new version (I say "probably" as there's a big gap between 2.7.6 and 2.14.0). You can't just copy one folder. As you've found, the cache directory does not contain all the information about the table.